# SWT - Image Resource to store all my images in one location

Tags: java, image, swt, imageicon

I have a package named images in my src directory.  I have quite a few images that I use in my project.  I use a method in my only Swing class to get Icons.

```
 public Icon getIcon(String name) {
    Icon icon = null;
    URL url = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
       url = classLoader.getResource(name);
       icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Couldn't find " + getClass().getName() + "/" + name);
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return icon;
}
```

To get a Icon

```
getIcon("/images/pdfClose.png");
```

This works great for Icons, but in my SWT classes, I use Images.

Is there a way in SWT to copy what the getIcon() method is doing?
Is it possible to rewrite the method to get images?

```
public ImageIcon getImage(String name) {
   ImageIcon image = null;
   URL url = null;
   ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   try {
     url = classLoader.getResource(name);
     image = new ImageIcon(url);
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't find " + getClass().getName() + "/" + name);
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
 return image;
}
```

I know it throws the error
**This instance method cannot override the static method from Dialog**

But is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see, where you are struggling. This is what I do to load images:

```
public static Image loadImage(String path, boolean inJar)
{
    Image newImage = null;

    try
    {
        if(inJar)
        {
            newImage = new Image(null, YOUR_MAIN_CLASS.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
        }
        else
        {
            newImage = new Image(null, path);
        }
    }
    catch(SWTException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

Note that I don't keep my images in the `src` folder, since that folder is for source files. I have a folder `img` in the root of the project and access the images via:

```
Image image = Images.loadImage("img/myImage.png", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Utils class in windows builder that you might want to look at to keep resources at one place and  make sure you dispose them.

http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.rcp/resources/1.4/org/eclipse/wb/swt/SWTResourceManager.java

Answer (score 1):

From the URL of an image file to get SWT image we need not get the ImageIcon first, the below example code we can get the SWT image from the URL,

```
Image imgSWT=null;  // Image class is the SWT Image class
ImageDescriptor imgDesc=null;
java.net.URL imgURL = YourClassName.class.getResource("path/image_filename");

if (imgURL != null) {
    imgDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(imgURL);
    imgSWT = imgDesc.createImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder named "res" under your project. Put all the images under this folder.

```
File file = new File("res/yourImage.Extension");
Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), file.getPath());
```